# React JS сбрасывает setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вопрос следующий. Есть такая функция которая меняет стейт, но он меняется только локально, и сразу после этого сбрасывается на дефолт. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
handleSend() {
  try {
    axios.post('/login', {
      posted_data: this.state.value,
      window_size: this.state.range_val,
      sin: this.state.value1,
      sin_v: this.state.value2
    }).
    then((response) => this.setState(() => {
      return {
        token: response.data['data']
      }
    }));

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(` Axios request failed: ${e}`);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: может где-то еще setState

Comment: попробуйте this.setState({token: response.data["data"]})